# How do I read the Apple Wallet Walgreens Loyalty card using APDU?

Tags: nfc, apdu, applepay, emv

Apple Wallet supports the Value Added Services protocol. I want to use this to read the Walgreens loyalty card (the only NFC-enabled loyalty card I have), to better understand the technology.

The APDU commands needed for this can be found on page 68 in the NFC.15 spec, where APDU command SELECT FILE is described:
http://www.gsma.com/digitalcommerce/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/NFC.15-Version-1.0-Mobile-Commerce-NFC-Coupons-and-Acceptance-Technical-Proposal.pdf

Trancieving the following APDU SELECT FILE to the Apple Watch (while having the card selected)

```
00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 05 59 00 01 00
```

Returns

```
6A 82 (File not found)
```

From the documentation I expected this command to select the present loyalty card file, or a special response containing a list of more specific IDs if multiple files are available. What am I doing wrong? Does the Apple Wallet use a custom RID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Karl, You need the Merchant ID or Application ID. Without the AID (Based on the NFC Spec) you will not be able to get the Customer ID or even get any other data from the Reward pass. 
Check this blog entry for more details: 
http://flomio.com/2016/07/nfc-enabled-passes-on-apple-wallet/

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is wondering if simply specifying a different 2 byte `Application Code` after the RID of `A0 00 00 05 59`, which the NFC.15 document assumes is `00 01` will yield a successful file/application selection (`SW 90 00`), it won't.  I tried all 65,536 combinations of these two bytes with no luck.  So yes, some additional information is clearly needed.  The link above is now dead, so I have raised a support inquiry with Apple Pay (as other posts mention) to see if the documentation required by NFC terminal makers/integrators can be made available under NDA.  So far the Apple support team is giving me a bit of a runaround but I think once they understand that I'm seeking non public documentation I'll get the information I need :) I'll keep this post updated if they respond to my inquiry.